# Creating a database for due dates

Tags: table, date

In my current role I have to write down all my projects on pre-made grid on a dry erase board.  As I finish a project I erase it but as the board reaches its capacity I have to manually shift everything by re-writing so space can be made for new projects.

How can I re-create this in MS Access or Excel?

Comment: which RDBMS database are you using/creating?

Comment: Welcome to DBA.SE! As it stands, this question is extremely broad and is unlikely to get a good quality answer. Please can you provide more information? Detail what you have tried so far, what your exact problem is, any code that you may have etc...

Comment: Have you considered to use any free on-line tools like asana.com or visualstudio (if you have a license)?